# Validation for model forms

Tags: django, python-2.7, modelform

I am trying to do validation for model forms to check if both 'email' and 'confirm_email' have same value. I tried searching online but getting some errors. I am making custom validators in models.py file.

Can you please help me with that. What would be the best way of validating model forms.

Here is my code.

MODELS.PY

```html
from django.db import models

from django.core import validators

from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
# Create your models here.
def validate_equal(self, email, confirm_email):
    if email != confirm_email:
        raise ValidationError(
        ('email does not match'),
        params={'email': email, 'confirm_email': confirm_email}
        )

class NewSubscriber(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254,unique=True)
    confirm_email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, validators=[validate_equal('self', 'email', 'confirm_email')])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do validation like that, especially when you want to compare fields. All you're doing here is passing the literal strings 'email' and 'confirm_email' (as well as 'self', for some reason) - and you're calling the validation function at define time.

Instead, use a clean method on the form itself.

```
class NewSubscriberForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['email'] != self.cleaned_data['confirm_email']:
            raise forms.ValidationError('email does not match')
        return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Daniel!